# Почему бот зацикливается на одной команде?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Написал бота начинает работу по команде решил расширить ему функционал дополнительными командами, но почему то он на них реагирует выборочно и то после его перезагрузки. То есть если вести команду0 то дальше какую команду не введи срабатывать будет код команды0.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['ПОМОЩЬ'])
def help(message):
    
    if message.chat.id == user_id:
        if user_id in allowed_ids:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="СПИСОК КОМАНД:\n"
                                                   "\n"
                                                   "команда0.\n"
                                                   "\n"
                                                   "команда1.\n"
                                                   "\n"
                                                   "команда2.")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В доступе отказано!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['команда0'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, введите сообщение...')
    if message.text != '':
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
        def all_messages(message):


            if message.chat.id == user_id:
                if user_id in allowed_ids:

                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-134354234545', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-5673423425', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-6797897897', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-67587766767', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-345256456346', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass

                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В доступе отказано!')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['команда1'])
def polyclinic_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, введите сообщение для ПОЛИКЛИНИК')
    if message.text != '':
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
        def nic_messages(message):
           
            if message.chat.id == user_id:
                if user_id in allowed_ids:
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-4356354564654', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-4564654654654654', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass

                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В доступе отказано!')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['команда2'])
def tal_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, введите сообщение')
    if message.text != '':
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
        def tal_messages(message):

            
            if message.chat.id == user_id:
                if user_id in allowed_ids:
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-65565646464', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-545465465466', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass
                    try:
                        bot.forward_message('-5465465656564', message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                    pass

                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В доступе отказано!')
```

Comment: @oleksandrigo  как поступить если их туда не пихать, а оставить вне тогда вообще всё работает не правильно, в предложенной вами статье управление идёт через одну команду у меня их четыре стоит новый вопрос задать или этот исправить?

Comment: Вам просто нужно юзать register_next_step_handler и все, будь у вас хоть 10 команд ничего не меняется. Прочитайте статью внимательнее